# Real time update in jquery working only for one form field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

*It's my first post on stackoverflow so excuse any of my faux pas regarding code posting etc., guys.*

So I am writing this social network and have most of the things working except for I cannot figure out why I cannot update the profile information using jQuery. It only seems to work for the first field (name), it posts data to the server and returns it. As long as I want to work on the second field (about) it returns an empty box and data is not inserted. I tried checking the spelling, typos etc. but I think the fault lays in the logics.

**HTML:**

```
<br/>Name<br/>
<input type="text" size="50" id="input_text" value="<?php echo getUser($_SESSION['user_id'], 'name'); ?>"/>
<input type="button" value="Change..." id="name_update_btn"/>

<br/>About<br/>
<input type="text" size="50" id="input_text_2" value="<?php echo getUser($_SESSION['user_id'], 'about');?>"/>
<input type="button" value="Change..." id="about_update_btn"/>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$( document ).ready(function(){

    $( '#name_update_btn' ).click( function(){

        $.post( "update.php?person_name=true", {
            person_name : $ ('#input_text').val()
        }, function( data ){
            $('#input_text').val( data );
        })
    });

    $( '#about_update_btn' ).click( function(){

        $.post( "update.php?about=true", {
            about : $ ('#input_text_2').val()
        }, function( data ){
            $('#input_text_2').val( data );
        })
    });
});
```

**PHP (update.php):**

```
if(isset($_POST['about'])==true){
    update($_SESSION['user_id'], 'about', $_POST['about']);
}

if(isset($_POST['avatar'])==true){
    update($_SESSION['user_id'], 'avatar', $_POST['avatar']);
}

if(isset($_POST['person_name'])==true){
    update($_SESSION['user_id'], 'name', $_POST['name']);
}
```

Anyone who could help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no php expert but it seems to me that the second use of POST should user `person_name` instead of `name`; when used within the `update` method call...

So like this

```
if(isset($_POST['person_name'])==true){
    update($_SESSION['user_id'], 'name', $_POST['person_name']);
}
```

Perhaps you should just keep things consistent and either use `name` or `person_name` and don't mix the 2?

So your jquery is like this

```
$.post( "update.php?name=true", {
    name : $ ('#input_text').val()
}, function( data ){
    $('#input_text').val( data );
})
```

and your php is like this

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])==true){
    update($_SESSION['user_id'], 'name', $_POST['name']);
}
```

your html already uses `name`

```
value="<?php echo getUser($_SESSION['user_id'], 'name'); ?>"
```

Comment: This guy deserves answer acceptance, he was first with the right answer.

Comment: The getUser is a defined function that returns a name from the database, so in HTML 'name' is used to address a field called 'name' in my database. The thing is that the field person_name works perfectly fine, updates and returnes the correct value but still the field ABOUT cannot be updated and returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

*This section was wrong*

*Edit:*

Now I see what's the problem. in the one but last line in PHP you have $_POST['name'] and it should be $_POST['person_name']. Besides - you don't have to do

```
if(isset($_GET['person_name'])==true){
```

This will be enough:

```
if(isset($_GET['person_name'])){
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your jquery function with LIVE method like -

```
$('#name_update_btn').live('click', function(){

      // code

});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, live() method has been deprecated in jQuery 1.7 and up. https://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 0):

For the future folks that might be stuck with something similar - I figured out what the problem was.
After fixing the naming problems as guys kindly pointed out I realized that my function "update" used here:

```
if(isset($_POST['person_name'])==true){
    update($_SESSION['user_id'], 'name', $_POST['person_name']);
}
```

was not returning any values and looked like this:

```
function update($user_id, $field, $update){
    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `$field` = '".$update."' WHERE `id` = ".(int)$user_id);
}
```

Therefore no value was returned and also no value was entered back to the form. Fixed function here:

```
function update($user_id, $field, $update){
    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `$field` = '".$update."' WHERE `id` = ".(int)$user_id);
    $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT `$field` FROM `users` WHERE `id` = ".(int)$user_id);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query2)){
            $updated = $row[$field];
    }
    return $updated;
}
```